# Can we use almost all standard Java packages in an android application?

Tags: java, android

I had created a Java application, which uses [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html) .I searched and found out we cannot use graphical libraries such as `AWT` or `Swing`.

So, can we use any standard Java library in an android application or there are some restrictions?
Also I observed JAI's jar file is unavailable in my android application (eclipse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a list of Java packages available on Android, consult the Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html